# Polymer Shadow Style from outside doesn't work in IE and FF

Tags: html, css, polymer

I have a custom Polymer-Element:

```html
<polymer-element name="lorem-element" noscript>
  <template>
   <h1>My Text</h1>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

I want to style the `<h1>` Tag from outside with the `::shadow` pseudo-element, like

```
lorem-element::shadow h1 {
    color : blue;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, but in the Firefox 33 and the InternetExplorer 11 it doens't work?!?!

Any advice how to make it work in FF and IE too?

Comment: Wait for them to support Shadow DOM in CSS...

Comment: There is support for polyfilling such selectors, but it requires a bit of work. There is documentation here https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#directives.